# Quiz on Internet safety

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code on execution in python 2.7 is giving an `NameError`.

The traceback is

```
answer1 = input("make a decision").Upper()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

The complete code is.

```
print("This is a quiz on Internet safety!")
print("Question 1")
print("What is a firewall?")
print("A-A killer hot wall!")
print("B-A protection from virus'")
print("C-A protection from bad websites!")
answer1 = input("make a decision").Upper()
if answer1 == "C":
    print("Good!")
    score = score+1
else:
    print("You failed....")
    quit
print("Question 2")
print("What is a virus?")
print("A-A killer disease! RUN!")
print("B-A harmful bit of mumbo-jumbo on the computer")
print("C-A harmful programme which encrypts the computer as invalid")
answer2 = input("make a decision").Upper()
if answer2 == "B":
    print("Well Done!")
    score = score+1
else:
    print("You failed....")
    quit
```

Comment: If it doesn't work then yes, the code is wrong.

Comment: please correct your indentation . and then tell that whats toe problem and whats your python version ?

Comment: Be more specific than "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: I do not know where the error is?

Comment: The code is not necessarily wrong, if you're not running Python3, it will fail. Also note that it's `upper`, not `Upper`.

Comment: What error do you get? What happens when you run it?

Comment: answer1 = input("make a decision").Upper()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'C' is not defined

Comment: Just a side comment: There is no correct answer for question 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the function is `upper` and not `Upper`

Secondly the program executes exactly in python3.

I you are using python 2, you need to use `raw_input` that returns string instead of `input` . Thus the line should be

```
answer1 = raw_input("make a decision").upper()
```

And the output will be perfect.

```
Question 1
What is a firewall?
A-A killer hot wall!
B-A protection from virus' 
C-A protection from bad websites!
make a decisionC
Good!
```

Also `quit` should be `quit()`

Comment: Please note that quit() (or exit()) should not be used in production code (RTFM). It has the (probably unexpected) side-effect of closing sys.stdin so just catching SystemExit is not enough. That won't make a difference here, but is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error it seems that you are using python 2 . so you need to use `raw_input` that return string . instead `input` . also you need to use `upper` instead `Upper` also seems that `score` and `quit` are extra here !

```
score = 0
print("This is a quiz on Internet safety!")
print("Question 1")
print("What is a firewall?")
print("A-A killer hot wall!")
print("B-A protection from virus'")
print("C-A protection from bad websites!")
answer1 = raw_input("make a decision").upper()
if answer1 == "C":
    print("Good!")
    score = score+1
else:
    print("You failed....")
    quit
```